# Access method from Collection own by model

Tags: backbone.js

My problem is to access model functions inside a collection.

I have an element structure like this :

- contentList (Collection)

  - content (Model)

    - svgStructure (Model)
    - svgParameterList(Collection)

      - cssStyle(Function)
      - svgParameter(Model)

        - changeStyle(Function)

mContent=new contentList();

And i want to call changeStyle function from my contentList object.
I tried this but it doesn't work

```
 valToSave = mContent.get(ici)  
 monstyle=valToSave.get("svgParameterList")  
 lulu=monstyle.cssStyle();  

/************************************ Model *******************************/
var content = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: function() {
  return {
    id : null,
    svgStructure: "",
    svgParameterList: ""
  };
},
initialize: function() {
    var self=this;
    this.svgStructure=new svgStructure();
    this.svgParameterList=new svgParameterList();
}
});


/************************************ Model *******************************/
var svgStructure = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: function() {
  return {
    id : null,
    name: ""};
}
});

 /************************************ Model *******************************/
 var svgParameter = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: function() {
  return {
    id : null,
    name: ""
  };
 },
changeStyle: function(){
    alert("ChangeStyle");
}
 });


 /************************************ Collection *******************************/
 var svgParameterList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(props) {
        var self=this;

    // on definit les comportement de la collection
        _.bindAll(this, "cssStyle");
        this.bind('reset', this.cssStyle);

        //les valeurs par default doivent etre coder en dur
        props=(props==undefined)?{model: svgParameter} : props;
        this.url=(props.url==undefined)? "model.json" : props.url;
        this.elem=(props.elem==undefined)? "#age" : props.elem;
        this.model=(props.model==undefined)? svgParameter : props.model;

        //on remplit avec les valeurs dans le fichier JSON
            //~ this.fetch();
    },

    cssStyle: function(){
        alert("cssStyle");
    }
});
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, how is it working?

Comment: and what is the code that returns undefined?

Comment: ooups! the cssStyle normaly return a value in my code. I simplify it to explain. And, thanks to your question, i realize that i just miss a return at the end of my code. Sorry !